# undefined method `link_to_remote' in MiniTest for application_helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

While migrating  an application from **Rails 2.3.17** to **3.2.21.**. We are facing an issue with Rails legacy form helper `link_to_remote` while testing with MiniTest.

In older version of rails we have used **link_to_remote** form helper which is removed in Rails 3. To provide support we have added **prototype_legacy_helper plugin** in our application which works fine in UI but tests for that fails and throws error like given below:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `link_to_remote' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:0xc800dd4>
```

This is our code inside ApplicationHelper

```
def reservation_menu_command_link(command, *args)
  ...
  command_link = link_to_remote(anchor_text,options = {}, {:class => style_class})
  ...
end
```

This is our test case for application_helper test

```
def test_reservation_menu_command_link
  options = { :lodging_view => lv}
  assert_equal(%q{xyz}, reservation_menu_command_link(:cancel_all_possible, options))
end
```

So you can see that we have a method reservation_menu_command_link and we used it inside our UI which works fine but test for this definition fails.

Could anyone can help me out from this behaviour of plugin?

Comment: Have you solve this issue? Could you add the information from your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, this issue is solved. I don't know the exact solution. I am using  **gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git`**  for Rails legacy helpers . If I get any proper solution I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

`link_to_remote` was deprecated between rails 2 and 3 the correct usage these days is

`link_to 'Foo', { action: 'create' }, remote: true`. Hopefully that helps